# How to capture actual POST data (the actual packet)?

Tags: perl

In a Perl script I am POSTing the data using LWP::UserAgent->new. Could anyone please tell me how to capture the actual data packet before it actually posts the data?

This is how I POST:

```
my $response = $browser->post($authUrl,
     [ 'username' => $username, 
       'response' => $pwdChallenge
     ]);
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you just want to see the HTTP request being sent? If so, both HTTP::Request and HTTP::Response have `as_string` methods that return a text version of themselves.